# Jackson serialization exception when trying to serialize LocalDateTime

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I can't figure why when trying to serialize an object I get an exception which looks related to deserialization. My object has a field which is of joda type LocalDateTime

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValueAsString(response));
```

I got the following exception:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.joda.time.LocalDateTime
```

I am trying to serialize. Why it is trying to convert String value to object? I tried to add custom deserializers, but it does not work.

**update** More of the exception:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.joda.time.LocalDateTime (through reference chain: com.my.AccountDetailResponse["registrationDate"])
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:218) ~[jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:1.9.13]
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:183) ~[jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:1.9.13]
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.SerializerBase.wrapAndThrow(SerializerBase.java:140) ~[jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:1.9.13]
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:158) ~[jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:1.9.13]
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112) ~[jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:1.9.13]
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:610) ~[jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:1.9.13]
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:256) ~[jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:1.9.13]
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:2575) ~[jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:1.9.13]
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:2097) ~[jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:1.9.13]
```

tried to add deserializer:

```
CustomDeserializerFactory deserializerFactory = new CustomDeserializerFactory();
    deserializerFactory.addSpecificMapping(LocalDateTime.class, new   CustomLocalDateTimeDeserializer());
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setDeserializerProvider(new StdDeserializerProvider(deserializerFactory));
    try {
        remoteActionDto.setPayload(mapper.writeValueAsString(response));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Can not convert response to json!", e);
       .....
    }
```

the deserializer itself. I does not convert actually, but only proof of concept:

```
private static class CustomLocalDateTimeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return new LocalDateTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: More code & more exception would be good. How did you try adding the customer (de)serializers? Where did the exception occur?

Comment: I added more info, but the thing that drives me crazy is why it try to convert string to object when I am trying to do the opposite!

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem (or actually a colleague of mine did it). It is the most stupid java behaviour I've ever met. The problem was, that the DTO which contained the **LocalDateTime** field was populated via *reflection*, and it seems possible to successfully set a value of type `String`. A class cast exception occurs when you try *to use* this field (not when it is being set).

```
public class MyDto {
  // trough reflection, the contained object is a java.lang.String
  private LocalDateTime myDate; 
}
```

If you ask why this happened - because we haven't configured a **converter** for `LocalDateTime`, but for `DateTime` instead. My colleague used `LocalDateTime` by mistake and Jackson silently deserialized it as a `String`

Comment: I don't think it possible in any way to assign `String` on `LocalDateTime` this way. JVM would prevent that. What IS possible, however, is with generics: if type was declared with type parameter like `T`, then internally it will be expressed as `java.lang.Object` (or if bound, lower bound type), and that assignment would proceed and produce exception when trying to access value.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a quick test class to check what you've provided. It seems to run fine and output the following:

```
{"value":[2014,2,24,13,42,44,745]}
```

Granted, that may not be the exact format you're looking for, but either way, here is the class:

```
public class JsonSerialization {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        try {
            final Response response = new Response();

            final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            final String value = mapper.writeValueAsString(response);
            System.out.println(value);
        }
        catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static class Response {
        LocalDateTime value = new LocalDateTime();
        public LocalDateTime getValue() {
            return this.value;
        }
        public void setValue(final LocalDateTime value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I guess this raises the questions:

- Do you have getters and setters for your LocalDateTime property (`registrationDate`)?
- Are you sure the error is occurring where you think it is occurring? The exception is just the part about Jackson, where does it say the `writeValueAsString` method is called within *your* code?

---

I know this isn't part of your question, but in 1.9.13 of Jackson, you should register custom (de)serializers like so:

```
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("", new Version(1, 0, 0, "");
module.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, new CustomLocalDateTimeDeserializer());
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

Answer (score 0):

Register your mapper with JodaModule module.

```
mapper.register(new JodaModule())
```

Or try with JodaMapper:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaMapper;

public static void main(String args[]){
     DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(12353434);
     JodaMapper mapper = new JodaMapper();
     try {
        serializedString = mapper.writeValueAsString(dateTime);
        System.out.println(serializedString);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Console Output:

```
12353434
```