# Jackson tries to cast Integer to String

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have a very basic Spring Boot app with .-data-jpa, .-data-rest and .-web dependencies.
In my model there is an entity `Game` that contains an Integer property `homeGameSwitch`.
When I get the resource with a REST call I get this exception:

> .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to write HTTP
>   message:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException:
>   Could not write JSON: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.String; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: java.lang.Integer
>   cannot be cast to java.lang.String (through reference chain:
>   org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$PersistentEntityResourceSerializer$1["content"]->com.coli.stripebackend.model.Game["homeGameSwitch"])

I find it strange that Jackson can't handle an Integer.
Is there something I can do prevent this error?

The entity:

```
@Entity
public class Game {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private Integer homeGameSwitch;

    public Integer getHomeGameSwitch() {
        return homeGameSwitch;
    }
```

The DAO:

```
@Repository("gameDao")
public interface GameDao extends JpaRepository<Game, Integer> {}
```

The service:

```
@Service("gameService")
public class GameServiceImpl implements GameService {

    @Autowired
    private GameDao gameDao;

    @Override
    public Game retrieveGameById(Integer id) throws Exception {
        Optional<Game> optionalGame = gameDao.findById(id);
        return optionalGame.get();
    }
```

The error occurs when calling localhost:8080/game/7

Comment: Show us your entity (or at least the least code necessary to reproduce the problem) and what exactly you're doing to get this exception. Read also [mcve] and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (more precisely point (1)).

Comment: @Coli, since the -1 was not from me, perhaps address that to whoever it was

Comment: You're still missing some info. You first said you were using spring-data-rest, but you're not using any REST repository, so where exactly is the code that is being served when you call `/game/7`?

Comment: I'm still learning, but following [this tutorial](https://www.lynda.com/Spring-Framework-tutorials/Advanced-lookup-APIs-search-resource/510079/571077-4.html?srchtrk=index%3a5%0alinktypeid%3a2%0aq%3aspring+boot%0apage%3a1%0as%3arelevance%0asa%3atrue%0aproducttypeid%3a2) when using spring-data-rest it is not necessary to add any code to have a REST API. The fact that the error comes after the retrieval from the DB proves that the REST API is working with this URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the version of Spring Boot. I was using the version 2.0.0.M2 in which there seems to be a bug.
I don't have the problem when using the version 1.5.4.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning to future readers who come here: There are many ways to trigger this exception: Some similar ones are collected in [Jackson serialization exception when trying to serialize LocalDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21988512/jackson-serialization-exception-when-trying-to-serialize-localdatetime)

It seems I just ran into another way of getting the exact same exception: Have a class like this:

```java
class Foo extends HashMap<String, String> {
  public long bar;
}
```

and try to serialize it.